# How to enable iCloud on broken iPod

Tags: icloud, apple-id, ipod

My iPod Touch turned off last night and after, it never woke up again. Is there any way to turn on iCloud Photo on this iPod by using my Mac? iCloud is working but not for photos, only for notes.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is dead, it's not going to be able to sync anything, even if you could otherwise switch it on remotely.

You can switch on photo sync from System Prefs > iCloud for cloud storage, or use iTunes or import using Photos or Image Capture... but all these methods require the device to still be capable of doing that.